# ClickOnce application uninstalls every time computer resets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, .net-4.6.1

I have multiple ClickOnce applications I have made for a few departments within the company I work for. These applications range from database entry to full QA reporting systems. I have noticed (and also had reported) that whenever I or any of the people using the programs restart their computer it seems to uninstall the program leaving only an icon that directs to the installer where they have to reinstall the application. They are small applications that install in seconds but it is still a little agitating that every time they restart their computers they have to reinstall the software. Is there something I am missing on the manifest/config/security settings within VS2012/VS2015 that will fully install the application and keep it from needing reinstall ever reset? I have tried making it available offline, making it full trust, and a couple other things i found within the app properties and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Sounds more like an administrative thing. Ask your admin, maybe some policies will cause that.

Comment: Maybe the user profiles reset on restart of the machine?